# WFS URL Illegal property name

Tags: wfs, cql-filter

I've been trying to write a Python script for QGIS to load point-features from this WFS URL:

https://geo.api.vlaanderen.be/Adressenregister/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

3 Steps: I first want to load the features, then clip them in a bounding box (WFSrootBB). After that, I want to save the features to an already existing shapefile layer ('opslaan wfs als shapefile').

My current script looks like this: [image]

If I try to execute the script, none of the objects are loaded and I get this error message:
*'Laag WFS Grar: Downloaden van objecten voor laag Adressenregister:Adres mislukt of gedeeltelijk mislukt: WFS foutrapportage (code=InvalidParameterValue tekst=Illegal property name: geom for feature type Adressenregister:Adres). U kunt met F5 proberen om de laag opnieuw te laden'*

It's Dutch but this basically means that the download of the objects has failed due tot and illegal property name. So, I was wondering where I can find the correct 'property name'. Normally the WFS only has one layer: 'Adressenregister:Adres'. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Please do **not** post pictures of text (code or exceptions) it is very hard for users on some devices to read and always makes it harder for people to investigate or search for your problem.

Comment: Why not just request the features constrained by the bounding box as a zipped shapefile; which is supported by the service?

Comment: Should be `typenames` for a 2.0.0 GetFeature request

Answer (score 0):

This is the main point in the error message:

```
(code=InvalidParameterValue tekst=Illegal property name: geom for feature type Adressenregister:Adres)
```

Check the schema of the feature type with DescribeFeatureType request

https://geo.api.vlaanderen.be/Adressenregister/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&typenames=Adressenregister:Adres

The result shows that the name of the geometry attribute is not "geom".

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="AdresPositie" nillable="true" type="gml:PointPropertyType"/>
```

Use the correct geometry field name `AdresPositie`in the filter.

EDIT:

Here is a working example:

https://geo.api.vlaanderen.be/Adressenregister/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=getfeature&TYPENAMES=Adressenregister:Adres&SRSNAME=EPSG:31370&cql_filter=Intersects(AdresPositie,POLYGON((91657.679%20180064.905,%2091657.679%20186710.326,%20101502.614%20186710.326,%20101502.614%20180064.905,%2091657.679%20180064.905)))

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding it, but it still doesn't work (see screenshot below)

Comment: My script as for now:

Comment: rootGrarWFS = 'https://geo.api.vlaanderen.be/Adressenregister/wfs?service=WFS&request=getfeature&TYPENAME='

GrarWFS = QgsVectorLayer(rootGrarWFS + 'AdresPositie' + WFSrootBB,'WFS Grar','wfs')

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(GrarWFS)

Comment: I am not good at reading pyqgis code. Please add the http request that your code generates and sends to the WFS server. In plain text, please.

Comment: GrarWFS = QgsVectorLayer(rootGrarWFS + 'Adressenregister:Adres' + WFSrootBB,'WFS Grar','wfs') --> i changed 'Adressenregister:Adres' to 'Adrespositie' but no result.

Comment: Do I have to change something about this? >>>                  WFSrootBB = '&SRSNAME=EPSG:31370&cql_filter=Intersects(SHAPE,POLYGON((91657.679 180064.905, 91657.679 186710.326, 101502.614 186710.326, 101502.614 180064.905, 91657.679 180064.905)))'

Comment: This is the root for my WFS:                 rootGrarWFS = 'https://geo.api.vlaanderen.be/Adressenregister/wfs?service=WFS&request=getfeature&TYPENAME='

Comment: The URL should be something like this: https://geo.api.vlaanderen.be/Adressenregister/wfs?service=WFS&request=getfeature&TYPENAME=AdresType&SRSNAME=EPSG:31370&cql_filter=Intersects(POINT,POLYGON((91657.679 180064.905, 91657.679 186710.326, 101502.614 186710.326, 101502.614 180064.905, 91657.679 180064.905)))

Comment: See my edited answer. You may need to read some WFS documents about what should be inserted into TYPENAMES and what is the meaning of the first parameter in geometry comparisons with cql_filter.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!